# Type Error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

```
def FindBestGamma(u,DLx,DLy,DLcon,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0,varinterval):
    u=5
    g = np.linspace(0.,1.,u)
    gammaPossible = np.array([seq for seq in itertools.product(g, repeat=u-1) if abs(sum(seq) - 1.0) < 1.0e-4])
    i = 0
    lv = []
    while i < len(gammaPossible):
        L = []
        j = 0
        while j < 1000:
            var = np.array(sampler(varinterval).next())
            tmp =LV(DLx[i],DLy[i],DLcon[i],gammaPossible[i],var,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0)
            L.append(tmp)
            j = j+1
        lv.append(max(L))
        i = i+1
    # return np.argmax(np.array(lv))#
    gamma = gammaPossible[np.argmax(np.array(lv))]
    return gamma

def forwd(x,y,gamma,var,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0):
    [mux1,muy1,sigmax1,sigmay1,rho1,mux2,muy2,sigmax2,sigmay2,rho2,mux3,muy3,sigmax3,sigmay3,rho3,mux4,muy4,sigmax4,sigmay4,rho4] = var
    return gamma[0]*ff(x,y,mux1,muy1,sigmax1,sigmay1,rho1,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[1]*ff(x,y,mux2,muy2,sigmax2,sigmay2,rho2,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[2]*ff(x,y,mux3,muy3,sigmax3,sigmay3,rho3,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[3]*ff(x,y,mux4,muy4,sigmax4,sigmay4,rho4,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0)
```

This is a sample of a section from my code. Whenever I try to run the whole code, I get the error:  'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**' in my def forwd section. I think it has to do with  the gamma calculation because when I test the code by giving gamma a set array such as `gamma=[0.0,0.0,0.25,0.75]`, the code works. How do I fix the code to prevent the error in the forwd section?

```
File "/Users/maryjacketti/Desktop/SOSim/sunkunoil/s4.py", line 71, in integ
    return forwd(x,y,gamma,var,x0new,y0new,t,sigmax0,sigmay0)*LV(DLx,DLy,DLcon,gamma,var,x0,y0,tt,sigmax0,sigmay0)
  File "/Users/maryjacketti/Desktop/SOSim/sunkunoil/s4.py", line 49, in forwd
    return gamma[0]*ff(x,y,mux1,muy1,sigmax1,sigmay1,rho1,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[1]*ff(x,y,mux2,muy2,sigmax2,sigmay2,rho2,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[2]*ff(x,y,mux3,muy3,sigmax3,sigmay3,rho3,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0) + gamma[3]*ff(x,y,mux4,muy4,sigmax4,sigmay4,rho4,x0,y0,t,sigmax0,sigmay0)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is the error I get.

Comment: please indent and format your code

Comment: Please show us the traceback rather than just a description of the error, so we know exactly what went wrong and on which line.

Comment: But the error obviously means that somewhere, you've got a function, and you're doing `func[something]`, which is illegal. Whether you wanted that `func` to be an array rather than a function, or wanted to call `func(something)`, or something else, is pretty hard to guess.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is too much lacking from your code snippet to even attempt reproducing your problem, let alone find the bug.